# python tkinter <function myClass.MyMethod at 0x000000000566D268>

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create some code that inserts text from a txt file into a textbox and I keep on getting the named error inside of the textbox and I have no idea how to fix it. I have looked at many other errors with a type of my error in it and still I have no idea what to do to fix this code. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

```
class myClass():
    def MyMethod():
       t = open('Notepad.txt', 'r')
       return t.read()

def New_Window():
    window = Toplevel(tk)
    window.geometry("400x400")
    window.title("NotePad")
    window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    t = Text(window, height=20, width=45)
    t.grid(column=0, row=0)
    message = myClass.MyMethod
    t.insert(0.0, message)
    Button(window, text="Quit", command=tk.destroy).grid(column=0,row=5)
    Button(window, text="Save", command=lambda: Save()).grid(column=0, row=6)

def Save():
    text = t.get('1.0', END)
    open('Notepad.txt', 'w').close()
    f = open('Notepad.txt', 'a')
    f.write(text + '\n')
    messagebox.showinfo('-- COMPLETE --', 'Saved', icon='info')
    f.close()
```

Comment: `message = myClass.MyMethod` assigns *the method itself* to the variable.  `message = myClass.MyMethod()` would assign the *result of calling the method*.

Comment: Just a quick aside, your method names should all be lower case `def my_method`, `def new_window`, `def save`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code. The following passes the method itself to the `message` variables

```
message = myClass.MyMethod
```

You need to add parenthesis to the method in order to call it and saving the returned value in the variable

```
message = myClass.MyMethod()
```